# How to summarize daily event data as weekly total and weekly moving average in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have event data that occurs on a daily timeframe, with the possibility for multiple events on the same day. I would like to create a chart in Power BI that depicts the total number of events in a week as well as a 2-week moving average over time.

| Date | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | Event 1 |
| 01/01/2023 | Event 2 |
| 01/02/2023 | Event 3 |
| 01/04/2023 | Event 4 |
| 01/05/2023 | Event 5 |
| 01/05/2023 | Event 6 |
| 01/07/2023 | Event 7 |
| 01/07/2023 | Event 8 |
| 01/10/2023 | Event 9 |
| 01/11/2023 | Event 10 |
| 01/12/2023 | Event 11 |

I've been able to create a chart with total events by week using a customer Calendar Table but cannot seem to get a Moving Average to display on the same chart.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the summarization of daily events to a weekly numbers (i.e. Count of events) requires a dedicated date table. I recommend reading on the benefits of date tables. Remember to set it as a date table.

As for the weekly rolling average you could do this through the quick measure called "Rolling Average". There you can determine the period of the average yourself.
This measure would essentially do the same. Replace [Your Measure] with your calculation, i.e. count of events:

> Moving AverageX 7 Days :=
> AVERAGEX (
> DATESINPERIOD (
> 'YourDateTable'[Date],
> LASTDATE ( 'YourDateTable'[Date] ),
> -7,
> DAY
> ),
> [Your Measure]
> )